# Can we add single reference to multiple .svc files in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a wcf application and host it on my web server, then I have add the service reference of this application to my client application.

All is working fine, the result I am getting is also as I have expected, the only thing I have a doubt is that after adding the service reference it adds some of the binding settings to the web.config file. So when I will be adding reference of multiple .svc files each time the binding settings will go on increasing, the point is that will their be a problem in managing these binding if I want to remove or add any references if they increases.

Another point is that if I want to create a wcf service layer to my project then I will have to add reference for all my classes to my client application and as a result the bindings in my web.config file will go on increasing.

Is their any way so I can add a single reference of my complete service layer to my client application?

Comment: Next time, please use some paragraphs..

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean by increasing bindings, but I would advise you to create a new class library that contains service references (WCF proxies) to all relevant services.

Then from whatever project you require to access the services, you add a reference to this new class libary and configure the services in the consuming application's config.

You can also easily apply one bindingconfiguration to multiple bindings, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new service reference the following elements will be automatically added to your web.config:

- An endpoint (**configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint**).  This identifies *where* the service is.  You need one for each service, so sharing one endpoint between multiple references is not an option.
- A binding (**configuration/system.serviceModel/bindings/binding**).  This tells the endpoint *how* to connect to the service.  Multiple service references can use the same binding, but obviously changes to the binding will affect both endpoints.  By default you will probably find that the binding type is `basicHttpBinding`.  To change an endpoint to use an existing binding, simply update the `bindingConfiguration` property of the endpoint and delete the binding you no longer need.

If you want to remove the reference, then simply right click on the reference in your solution explorer and select delete.  The endpoint and binding will be automatically removed.

**Only unused bindings will be removed**: so if your binding is used by multiple endpoints you can safely delete an associated reference.  The binding will remain unless it is no longer needed.